# TabOrder in DBGridEh on Delphi

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid, tab-ordering

Good morning all.

I have a DBGridEh like this:

[image: DBGridEh]

When I press Tab Button first time, the taborder does normally (left to right). But when i am in last column, i press tab and it focus on Bodega column. Why not is focusing on Referencia column?

UPDATE: I solved part of the problem with this code on KeyPress event:

```
DBGridItems.SelectedIndex := DBGridItems.FieldColumns['codigo_ref'].Index;
DBGridItems.Columns[DBGridItems.SelectedIndex].Field.FocusControl;
```

When no info on line, it gets on Referencia column, but when I create a new line, it gets me to Bodega column yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried contacting EhLib, or at least check their forums?  Here's post about changing the tab order http://forum.ehlib.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=354&hilit=grid+tab+order

Comment: I solved part of the problem with this code on KeyPress event:    
    DBGridItems.SelectedIndex := DBGridItems.FieldColumns['codigo_ref'].Index;
   DBGridItems.Columns[DBGridItems.SelectedIndex].Field.FocusControl;

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the tab order was: the 'Referencia' column in ReadOnly property was TRUE because of a procedure that was putting the column like that. If the column is in ReadOnly, the tab order avoid that column.

The solution was: erase the column of the procedure and the tab order is locating now on the desired column.